# Retrieve a specific character from text and his number. I.e 92%. Unix

Tags: shell, unix, server

I am extracting data information from a unix server regarding data usage with the below command

```
df -P /data >> /data/prod/schjobs/data_usage.txt
```

The output on the text is the below:

```
'Filesystem             512-blocks  Used  Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/vg02/lv_sas_data_raid1 4271649954 3922870768 348779186    92%     /data'
```

What i want to ask is how i retrieve the `92%` number in order to compare it after that and probably sent a notification mail and delete some folders in order to clear some space.

Could you please help ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PanagiotisIoannidis : You could first use `tail` or `grep` to extract the desired line from `data_usage.txt`, and then (for instance) `cut` to extract the field. In case you know for sure that data_usage.txt contains at most one percentage figure, it is easier to extract it with `grep -oE '[0-9]+%'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use below command to get the value `92%`:

```
SPACE=$(df -P /data |tail -1 |awk '{print $5}')
echo $SPACE
```

Also, the same goes with the redirected `.txt` file as well:

```
SPACE=$(cat /data/prod/schjobs/data_usage.txt |tail -1 |awk '{print $5}')
echo $SPACE
```

Subsequently you can use the `if` condition to compare the disk space ,sending the mail notification and then cleaning up the space by removing the largest files/directories.

***EDIT ANSWER***

To get the value without `%`, you can simply pipe the output to a `cut` command as below and then use that variable for the comparison:

```
SPACE=$(df -P /data |tail -1 |awk '{print $5}' |cut -d '%' -f1)
echo $SPACE
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi User123,  thanks for the answer i just closed the parenthesis and works  great. However i think i should remove the % in order to compare it. Correct? However i should convert it into a string ? Could you please help with that?

Comment: Please check my edited answer to get the value without `%`.  Usually in Unix systems(HP-UX,Linux ,Sun-OS) i get the value of `df` as `92 %`, i.e there exists one space between the number and the `%`, so it's easy for me to get the value using `awk` command.

Comment: Welcome. you can Accept and upvote the answer as well if it worked fine :-)

Comment: Of course i did it i am just a newbie for now and probably does not show it :D

Comment: 1) You can make `awk` treat things as numbers by adding zero to them (rather than using `cut`), so try this `echo "a b c d 92% e" | awk '{print $5+0}'`

Comment: 2) You can make `awk` use the last line (rather than using `tail`) like this `df | awk 'END{print}'`

Comment: 3) If your mount point has spaces, your field number may be incorrect, so you could count backwards from the right, rather than forwards from the left `df | awk 'END{print $(NF-1)+0}`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Thanks sir for your comments, learned some better ways of scripting :)

Comment: We're all here to learn and share! Your answer was already fine and already has my vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value in a variable like below

```
TOTAL_OCCUPIED=$(echo 'Filesystem 512-blocks Used Available Capacity Mounted on /dev/vg02/lv_sas_data_raid1 4271649954 3922870768 348779186 92% /data' | awk '{print $12}')
```

Or

```
 TOTAL_OCCUPIED=$(cat /data/prod/schjobs/data_usage.txt | awk '{print $12}')


 echo $TOTAL_OCCUPIED
```